# inserting huge number of rows to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I want to read from MSSQL table then insert in to MySQL table but i couldn't format my MSSQL results to `executemany` on them

```
    cursor.execute('select * from table') # MSSQL
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    many_rows = []
    for row in rows:
        many_rows.append((row))
    sql = "insert into mysql.table  VALUES (NULL, %s) on duplicate key update REFCOLUMN=REFCOLUMN" # MYSQL
    mycursor.executemany(sql, many_rows)
    mydb.commit()
```

this gives `Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters`
First NULL is for id column and %s for other 49 columns. It works with 1 by 1 but takes ages over remote connection

**EDIT**

my example print output of `many_rows`:

```
[
(49 columns' values, all string and separated by comma),
(49 columns' values, all string and separated by comma),
(49 columns' values, all string and separated by comma),
...
]
```

Comment: _"First NULL is for id column and %s for other 49 columns"_ But you only gave placeholders for 1 [non-ID] column.... How many rows are we talking about? Can you provide an actual [MCVE]?

Comment: A real [MCVE] please not a mockup

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's actually my code except table names which are super long

Comment: So construct a [MCVE] that we can actually diagnose. So far you have not provided any real demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue with appending data like below:

`many_rows.append((list(row)))`